# Failed to load resource from bower_components using Vue.js CLI

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bower

In my project I receiving the following error when attempting to reference CSS and JS files

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

This is my file structure

```
app
    |bower_components
        |bootstrap
            |dist
                |css
                   | bootstrap.min.css
        |jquery
            |dist
                |jquery.min.js
    |build
    |config
    |node_modules
    |src
    |static
    |index.html //The file I am receiving error on
public //using Slim framework with PHP to generate RESTful API
src
vendor
```

In my `index.html` file I am using the following code to attempt to reference the bootstrap.min.css file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using Visual Studio Code, this enables to to be able to CTRL+click on the link to bootstrap.min.css file and it loads ok, so I am unsure where I went wrong here?

I am using `vue.js CLI` as the `app` folder and using the `Slim Framework` with `PHP` to generate a RESTful API in the `public/src/vendor` folders if that helps? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried removing the "./" from the link?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, still receiving the same error. I have tried with just using vue.js CLI and it works, so it definitely has something to do with that, just not sure how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue, it is linked with using Vue.js CLI.

I needed to add the bower_components folder into static folder and then reference the file just like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```